# How to get bitbucket's refresh_token?

Tags: bitbucket, token, access-token, bitbucket-api, refresh-token

I am using the below API

```
https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=token
```

to get access_token but access_token is expired in 1 hour and I need refresh_token but I am not able to get refresh_token in the above API's response. 
The response of above API is

```
https://www.example.com/#access_token={access_token}&scopes={scopes}&expires_in=3600&token_type=bearer
```

You can see in above response there is no 
Or is there any other way to get refresh_token.

I wanted to call the above API as GET method.

Can please someone help.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some solution. As I was using browser-based operations without server-side back-end support. In the [Atlassian doc](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/oauth-on-bitbucket-cloud-238027431.html) they have mentioned that Implicit and JWT are excluded the refresh_tokens. And If you want refresh_token as well then you need to use **Authorization Code Grant** first.

Answer (score 7):

In your browser go to

`https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/authorize?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code`

Authorize using your bitbucket account.

After that, your browser will be redirected to

`{your_redirect_link}/?code={code}`

Use the code to make another request in a terminal:

`curl -X POST -u "{client_id:secret}" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=authorization_code -d code={code}`

The reponse will be look like that:

```
{
  "access_token": "some_long_string",
  "scopes": "team webhook account issue wiki pipeline pullrequest project snippet",
  "expires_in": 7200,
  "refresh_token": "the_string_you_need",
  "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Now you can refresh access_token with a request

`curl -X POST -u "{client_id}:{secret}" https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token -d grant_type=refresh_token -d refresh_token={refresh_token}`

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: please note, after a revisit to this issue, I have to say my initial "solution" below is incorrect. [Petr's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53626762/830737) is more appropriate. Apologies if I caused any confusion.

---

I was just precisely facing this very question, thanks for entering it in SO!

Better yet, I just found the solution: You need to make a request for grant_type=client_credentials:

```
curl -X POST -u "your_client_id:your_secret" \ 
     https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token \
    -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

The refresh token will be included in the reply:

```
{
    "access_token": "the_access_token",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "refresh_token": "the_refresh_token",
    "scopes": "....",
    "token_type": "bearer"
}
```

Note that, regarding the refresh token itself, you need to make this request only once according to this [comment from Atlassian team member](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Does-the-oauth-2-refresh-token-expire/qaq-p/574230#M111888):

> ... refresh tokens do not expire. [...] Access tokens expire as per the spec, refresh tokens do not expire.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This solution I have found already but the thing is I wanted to use this with REST client instead of CURL. Do you have any idea regarding this?

Comment: Sorry, your "How to get bitbucket's refresh_token?" is what the indicated solution is about. If the actual question is how to use it to retrieve a "refreshed" **access token**:  As explained at https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/oauth-2/ this needs to be via a POST request to `https://bitbucket.org/site/oauth2/access_token` with basic authentication (using your client_id and secret), and form parameters: `grant_type=refresh_token` and `refresh_token=<your refresh token>`.  Consult your "REST client" doc to see how to make such request (or indicate what language/env you are using).